# MVC string value to hold Javascript code , but Js doesnt recognize quote

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor

I had this code trace in my Razor view

```
@{
    string markerPlacementScript = "alert('Hello')"; 
}
```

and use this in the javascript code block

```
<script> @markerPlacementScript </script>
```

But too bad , the javascript engine recognize the quote as ascii , hence

```
 alert(&#39;Hello&#39;)
```

How do I let Javascript to parse it as quote ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>@Html.Raw(markerPlacementScript)</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch , i've wasted 5 hours for this

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

look specifically for "Expression (Unencoded)"

```
<script> @Html.Raw(markerPlacementScript) </script>
```